# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (261, 25088) for Tensor 'Placeholder_26:0', which has shape '(?, 30)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am trying to classify my images features by loading bottleneck_features_train.npy, i do not now what is the Nº of inputs in D variable that's suits my data with shape (261, 25088.
here is my code

```
dataset1 = np.load('bottleneck_features_train.npy', encoding='bytes')
nsamples, nx, ny, nz = dataset1.shape
X = dataset1.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny*nz))
Y = generator.classes
Y = to_categorical(Y)
Y = np.argmax(Y, axis=1)
seed = 9
X_train, X_val,Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

D          = ??
m          = 16    # Rules
alpha      =  0.01 # Training rate
num_epochs = 600   # Nº of epochs
fis = ANFIS(n_inputs=D, n_rules=m, learning_rate=alpha)
```

i got the following error

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (261, 25088) for Tensor 'Placeholder_26:0', which has shape '(?, 30)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for the answer the best answer is that the D should equal to the second value (261, 25088) which is 25088

```
dataset1 = np.load('bottleneck_features_train.npy', encoding='bytes')
nsamples, nx, ny, nz = dataset1.shape
X = dataset1.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny*nz))
Y = generator.classes
Y = to_categorical(Y)
Y = np.argmax(Y, axis=1)
seed = 9
X_train, X_val,Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

D          = 25088
m          = 16    # Rules
alpha      =  0.01 # Training rate
num_epochs = 600   # Nº of epochs
fis = ANFIS(n_inputs=D, n_rules=m, learning_rate=alpha)
```